# Pointers towards using robot_localization for VO + Wheel odometry

Tags: navigation, ekf, visual-odometry, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey , i am trying to setup a EKF fusion for combining odometry coming from two topics

1. Visual Odometry (X , Y and yaw)
2. Wheel Encoders ( X , Y and yaw)

The main source of Odometry is coming from wheel encoders , the visual odometry is there much like a correction mechanism like while using IMUs. Having said that , my VO node publishes Twist values , is it better to fuse the wheel odometry using Twist values using robot_localization ?

*I am  getting the following error when i launch rviz to view the odometry*

```
Assertion `!pos.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
```

*I am confused with how the TF should be setup  .*
The TF of wheel encoder odometry is as follows

```
 frame_id: "odom"
 child_frame_id: "base_link"
```

TF of the visual Odometry is as follows

```
frame_id: "raspicam"
child_frame_id: ''
```

**AFTER LAUNCHING THE EKF NODE**

[image: image description]

**BEFORE LAUNCHING THE EKF NODE**

[image: image description]

** MY  EKF LAUNCH FILE LOOKS LIKE THIS **

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_custom" clear_params="true"> <!-- renamed to ekf_localization_custom to prevent name conflicts -->

  <param name="frequency" value="30"/> <!-- this value should be fine -->

  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/> <!-- this value should be fine -->

  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/> <!-- could make this true to stick to XY plane.. -->

  <!-- based these values off of the ROScon presentation -->
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/optical_flow"/>
  <param name="odom1" value="/ubiquity_velocity_controller/odom"/>
  
  <!-- settings for using Twist -->
  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false,  false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  true, true, false,
                                  false, false, true,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>


 <rosparam param="odom1_config">[false, false, false,  
                              false, false, true, 
                              true, true, false,   
                              false, false, true,
                              false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
  <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>
  <param name="publish_null_when_lost" value="false"/>
  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
  <param name="odom1_relative" value="false"/>

  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
<remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/visual" />
</node>
```

[EDIT #1 adding sensor data samples ]

**Wheel Odometry**

```
 header: 
  seq: 3786
  stamp: 
    secs: 1529497452
    nsecs: 845127379
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.50
      y: 0.20
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.01
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.8334
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.1233
  covariance: [0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]
```

**Visual Odometry**

```
header: 
  seq: 540
  stamp: 
    secs: 1529499662
    nsecs: 800348997
  frame_id: "raspicam"
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294668/pointers-towards-using-robot_localization-for-vo-+-wheel-odometry/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-06-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-06-20**:
Please post sample messages for every sensor input.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-20**:
Hey , I have edited the question and added the sample data . I think I have resolved the issue of rviz crashing , it was because the TF not set properly .

Now ,The covariance on the fussed output keeps building up into a larger and larger value. How do I systematically tackle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a few issues.

1. You are fusing velocities from your visual odometry source, but your visual odometry source has no `child_frame_id`. If you look at the [definition of nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html), you'll see that the `child_frame_id` is the TF frame of the twist (velocity) data, but you are leaving this empty. That means the EKF is going to ignore it completely.
2. You have `two_d_mode` set to *false*, which means you want a full 3D state estimate, but you are only fusing 2D variables. Unmeasured variables in the EKF will result in absolute explosions of those variables' covariance values, which will have irritating effects on other variables. Turn on `two_d_mode` or start measuring the other 3D variables.
3. Your state estimate covariance is growing without bound for your X and Y position, because you are only fusing velocity data for those. The filter will integrate those velocities, but it will also integrate their errors. If you had, for example, a laser scanner, you could localize against the map to provide X/Y position that would cap the growth in covariance. You are fusing two data sources that accumulate error over time, though, so endless growth in your covariance is actually appropriate. You should really fuse yaw velocity from your wheel encoders, and not absolute yaw.

Note, though, that if you fuse absolute X, Y, and yaw from your wheel odometry, AND your wheel odometry covariance is NOT calculated correctly (e.g., it's static, as opposed to growing without bound), that will cap the covariance as well, but it will be incorrect.

In general, yes, I recommend fusing velocity data for odometry sources, including visual odometry. If you had some means of localizing the robot globally (e.g., GPS or scan-to-map localization or overhead camera localization), you would fuse those absolute pose values.

**EDIT** in response to comments:

I'm not sure we're on the same page with what an IMU does or how it constrains drift (or doesn't). An IMU typically produces the following quantities:

1. Absolute roll, pitch, and yaw
2. Angular velocity
3. Linear acceleration

If you fuse roll, pitch, and yaw into the EKF, that data is coming from accelerometers and magnetometers, which are measuring the IMU's orientation with respect to a fixed frame. So if you fuse those values, you will constrain drift **only for those variables**, and their covariances will reach a steady-state and will stop growing.

If you fuse velocity or linear acceleration data from an IMU, but do NOT fuse the roll, pitch, or yaw data, your roll, pitch, and yaw covariance will grow without bound.

In this EKF, we are concerned with the following quantities:

1. X, Y, Z position - can be measured directly, or integrated from linear velocity data.
2. Roll, pitch, yaw - can be measured directly, or integrated from angular velocity data
3. X, Y, Z velocity - can be measured directly, or integrated from linear acceleration data
4. Roll, pitch, and yaw velocity - can only be measured directly
5. X, Y, Z acceleration - can only be measured directly

Any time your only data source for a variable comes from integration, that variable's covariance will grow without bound. So, if you fuse X, Y, and Z velocity, your X, Y, and Z velocity covariance will be bounded, but your X, Y, and Z position covariance will grow without bound.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-26**:
https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/visual-odometry-full/

I am taking this approach to build my visual odometry node .

But the drift is just too much . What if i use the Visual Node as simply an error correction node much like a IMU enabled EKF localization node .

Are there other  similar work?

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-26**:
My greatest constraint is Computational power .

I have to run everything on a RPI3B+ .

I have already tried Viso2 ,  ORB-SLAM2 ,RPG-SVO .(Too Slow!)

recently came across [Rebvo](https://github.com/JuanTarrio/rebvo) , yet to test it .

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-06-26**:
Even if you did that, the error you're correcting is error in *velocity* measurement, not pose measurement. Odometry accumulates error over time, and you covariance will reflect that. The only way to constrain drift in the EKF output is to have an absolute pose measurement.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-26**:
While using an IMU , we are not getting an absolute pose , right?

So can a visual odometry node be used in a similar way ?

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-26**:
okay , now i understand better .
One last question , is there a way to estimate Angular Velocity and Linear Acceleration  ?

[recoverPose](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) returns , R – Recovered relative t – Recoverd relative transl

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-26**:
"Another problem occurs when the camera performs just pure rotation: even if there are enough features, the linear system to calculate the F matrix degenerates. "

What if i use wheel odometry as an absolute scale ?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-06-26**:
Your wheel odometry is generated by integrating encoder ticks. It has the same issue. If it's written correctly, the pose variables will have covariances that grow without bound.

Is it a problem for your covariances to grow? Or are you trying to reject bad measurements from your VO?